# chefspec: What is the difference between predicate matchers and attributes?

Tags: chef-infra, chefspec

For example, to check that a directory has been created with the user "nobody" I can use either of two [methods](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sethvargo/chefspec/ChefSpec/API/DirectoryMatchers#create_directory-instance_method):

"*Assert that a directory was createed with predicate matchers*"

```
expect(chef_run).to create_directory('/tmp').with_user('nobody')
```

"*Assert that a directory was createed with attributes*"

```
expect(chef_run).to create_directory('/tmp').with(user: 'nobody')
```

There is a third method using regexs but I'm not concerned with that method.

How do I go about deciding which method to use to assert that the directory was created and is owned by the correct user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference: https://github.com/chefspec/chefspec/blob/master/lib/chefspec/matchers/resource_matcher.rb#L32-L34

```
    def method_missing(m, *args, &block)
      if m.to_s =~ /^with_(.+)$/
        with($1.to_sym => args.first)
        self
      else
        super
      end
    end
```

The `with(user: whatever)` syntax is by far more common but it's up to you and your personal style.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the link.  Although this should be documented one would think.   I just assume no one would go through the effort of creating additional variations of syntax if there wasn't any difference in the outcome or side effects.

Comment: I mean 99% of what ChefSpec and RSpec do is syntactic sugar for tasks you can do other ways already so ... yes people do a lot of that.